# Preterito perfecto subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo, aspecto-gramatical

I have some questions regarding past tenses (in *indicativo* and *subjuntivo*).

I have noticed that in Spanish both past tenses (*imperfecto* and *preterito*) are actively used, depending on specific situation. At the same time it seems to be that among *subjuntivo* past tenses the most used one and learned is *subjuntivo imperfecto*. And I noticed subjectively that for almost all past actions it is the most preferred (for both different situations - when actions are one-time/ended AND when past action has been repeated and has no definite ending). Meaning that *subjuntivo preterito* is used rarely (*subjuntivo imperfecto* is preferred). Example below:

> I am glad you came, Henri. *Me alegro de que hayas venido, Henri*. [*pretérito subjuntivo perfecto*]

BUT I have also seen such examples for similar original English sentences, such as:

> Sara, I'm glad you came. *Sara, me alegra que vinieras.* [*preterito subjuntivo imperfecto*]
>   I am happy you did it. *Estoy feliz de que lo hicieras.* [*pretérito subjuntivo imperfecto*]

Based on this, is it safe to assume that while in indicativo both simple past tenses are used (*imperfecto* and *pretérito*) equally, and are equally important in everyday usage, when it comes to the *subjuntivo*, the *imperfecto* is almost always preferred instead of *pretérito* (even in cases when *subjuntivo* *pretérito* would be more appropriate)?

I am talking about everyday usage.

Comment: YMMV based on dialect, but I definitely quite actively use *hayas venido*.  *vinieras* is of dubious grammatically –despite its common usage– because it violates the sequence of tense.  Where the two *are* more fully merged is when the introductory sentence is in the past tense: *me alegraba de que vinieras* and never *me alegraba de que hayas venido*

Comment: I think this merits a separate answer, but I'm having trouble with the context. Alex, are you asking about the subjunctive **in these examples** and nothing else?

Comment: Well, these examples I provided are just to illustrate the confusion. I am more interested to know how is it dealt in everyday usage. So is subjuntivo imperfecto really used more often than subjuntivo preterito in most everyday situations EVEN in case when action has been finished (and so subjuntivo preterito would be more appropriate)? OR imperfecto subjuntivo and preterito subjuntivo are used equally often in everyday speech just like preterito indicativo and imperfecto indicativo?

Comment: The thing is, the confusion can be cleared for these examples, but there's no way to generalize it.

Comment: Anyway, I think I now got the understanding thanks to the comment from guifa that all 4 subjuntive tenses are equally important in both writing and everyday speech. I now believe that it was my mistake to view subjuntivo preterito as having no widespread usage.

Comment: For the pattern you are looking at, the imperfect is indeed more common.  "Sara, me alegra que vinieras" doesn't sound idiomatic to my ear.  But I don't know how to document this.